# How can I find and replace all occurrencies of a character in vim?

Tags: vim

I have a strange character in a text, how can I find all of its occurrences
and replace it with another character?

I know that if you need to do the same thing with a word you can use `*` and then `:%s//replacement/g` to replace all occurrences,

is  there something similar for characters?

Comment: please post the question in the [Super User](https://superuser.com/) sub-site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yank the character into a register (`a` in this case): `"ayl`
2. Start your substitute command `:%s/`
3. Use `<C-r>` `a` to paste the register into the command line.
4. Finish your command and execute: `:%s/<char>/<new-char>/g`

Answer (score 0):

Do you know how to type out the character? If so you can do `:%s/<char-to-replace>/<char-to-replace-with/g`

Comment: no I don't know... and `*` doesn't work because it finds the occurrences  of  the next word...

Answer (score 0):

Use the command:

```
%s/a/A/g
```

which replaces `a` with `A`. For some more examples of the `%s` command take a look [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace).